# SugarCRM CE calculated and editable fields

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a custom field(*cost*) in a custom module(*budget*) that it must be calculated based on a related field(*product*) selection and other field (*units*). So, its must be:

```
Cost = price(of selected product) * units.
```

It must be calculated when product is selected or units value is set, but it must be editable with another value if user wants.

I'm using SugarCRM CE version 6.1.4.

Comment: have you solved your issue ?

Comment: Yes. But a bit complicate.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this steps:
In my case, in quickcreatedefs.php add hidden files for loaded values of related module (its a bit more complex to calculate cost that my initial example):

```
 'form' =>
  array (
    'hidden' =>
    array (
      0 => '<input type="hidden" name="material_precio" id="material_precio" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_unidades_precio" id="material_unidades_precio" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_densidad" id="material_densidad" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_alto" id="material_alto" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_ancho" id="material_ancho" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_diametro" id="material_diametro" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_grosor_redondo" id="material_grosor_redondo" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_grosor_rect" id="material_grosor_rect" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="material_grosor_rect" id="material_grosor_rect" value="">',
    ),
```

In related field add:

```
'displayParams' => array (
            'field_to_name_array' => array(
                'id'=>'mater_preciosmaterial_id_c',                      //hidden id
                'detalle'=>'material',               
                'precio'=>'material_precio',
                'unidades_precio' => 'material_unidades_precio',
                'geometria' => 'material_geometria',
                'alto' => 'material_alto',
                'ancho' => 'material_ancho',
                'diametro' => 'material_diametro',
                'grosor_redondo' => 'material_grosor_redondo',
                'grosor_rect' => 'material_grosor_rect',
                'densidad' => 'material_densidad',
                ),
            'additionalFields' => array(
                'precio' => 'material_precio',
                'unidades_precio' => 'material_unidades_precio',
                'geometria' => 'material_geometria',
                'alto' => 'material_alto',
                'ancho' => 'material_ancho',
                'diametro' => 'material_diametro',
                'grosor_redondo' => 'material_grosor_redondo',
                'grosor_rect' => 'material_grosor_rect',
                'densidad' => 'material_densidad',
            ),
```

And use js to calculate cost, based on this hidden fields and fields enter by user (units, measures,...)

Hope it's helpfull for you